# Flutter SDK is not found Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-studio-3.5.3

I have updated my Android Studio, I am facing issue with flutter while creating new flutter project. I have set Environment Variable path as well as checked in cmd everything seems fine, but still it is giving error about Flutter SDK not found. Can any one suggest better solution for this issue ?

Comment: did you try in android studio's settings then -> languages and framework find flutter and setup flutter SDK there

Comment: yes I have tried that too, it was same error there also

Comment: had an issue with 3.5.1 and found this issue that solved my problem . https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3934  hopefully it will solve yours.

Answer (score 0):

First, run flutter doctor, it should tell something, and if it doesn't, issue will probably be with gradle, updating gradle causes a lot of problem, i suggest you delete your gradle located at C:\Users***.gradle, or even the sdk and open android folder of a flutter app in android studio, and let the correct settings install, sync and setup..